# Disable safari from unzip downloaded file

Tags: php, html, web, header, safari

I'm having a small problem with encrypted zip downloads in Safari. I've set all appropriate headers to force a download, but when the file's downloaded Safari tries to unzip it which results in a corrupt file. What I've read it's because Safari flags the file as safe and then tries to open it.

Is there a way to disable Safari from open the file after downloaded it?

Comment: Safari has an option "open safe files after downloading" I think it's not possible to keep safari from doing so without the client changing this setting

Comment: @Burbas: have you tried serving the file an incorrect MIME type? i.e. not `application/zip, application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't disable this server-side :(

It's Safari's default behavior to unpack archives after downloading them. This can be disabled in Safari: `Preferences` -> `General` -> Uncheck the box `Open "safe" files after downloading` at the bottom. But it's up to users themselves to do this.

If you like, you can display a warning about this behavior on the download page.

PS: The zip won't disappear! Safari may (optionally) unpack it, but the downloaded zip will still be next to the unpacked folder.

PPS: In 2022 (and according to the comments a couple years before) Safari will move the archive to the trash automatically. It's not completely deleted, but it's also not next to the unpacked folder anymore.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. It was as I though, but needed to be sure :-)

Comment: With me, the zip-file seems to be deleted. Only the folder remains

Comment: (I know it's old, but it was a top google result)
if you can't find the .zip after automatic unzipping, be sure to check your trash.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely not the most elegant version there is but you may end up using a browser junction and have your download script change attachment name in combination with a notice for Safari users:

```
<?php

// $attachmentId used later-on would be a passed parameter that is used 
// to define attachment name

$attachmentId= $_GET['id'];

$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if (strpos($userAgent , 'Chrome') === FALSE && 
strpos($userAgent , 'Safari') !== FALSE)
{
  $attachmentName= 'download.zipname';
  $userNotice= 'SAFARI users: please rename the file from download.zipname to download.zip (due to Safari\'s ZIP file policy (more info))';
} else {
  $attachmentName= 'download.zip';
  $userNotice= '';
}
?>
<span class="notice"><?php print $userNotice; ?></span>
<a href="download.php?id=<?php print $attachmentId;?>" name="<?php print $attachmentName; ?>">Download</a>
```

So basically before starting the download, you would set up this pre-download page to define the required attachment name and to inform safari users about what has to be done to successfully download the file.

Comment: you may even start the download in the else-case for non-Safari browsers (using `header()`, `echo()` and `exit()`) so the page would only be displayed for Safari users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's probably the direction I need to take, showing an ugly info-box to Safari-users :-)

Comment: @Burbas: I like this. Perhaps forego the notice altogether and just have it saved with an alias extension?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid but you can't work this on the server side.

You can't help this. It's on the user to check or uncheck to open the downloaded files using the WinZip or some other software.

At the max we can do is show them an alert/popup suggesting the usage of this format is not safe or something on the similar lines.

Answer (score -3):

You can use jQuery, where is safari you can hide or unhide a button or change the event of one button, etc.

```
if (jQuery.browser.mozilla){  
           // insert you code here
else if (jQuery.browser.msie){  
                        // insert you code here  
else if (jQuery.browser.safari){  
                        // insert you code here 
else if (jQuery.browser.opera){  
                 // insert you code here
} else {  
                       // insert you code here 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.